# LightTable - Adding auto complete keywords

Tags: clojure, ide, editor, lighttable

Is there a way to add additional auto complete keywords? From my experience with the IDE/Editor, some languages, like clojure, already have every function native to the language available as an auto complete word. Is it possible to add, say, every function from the seesaw library, or every function from the compojure library to that list? Is it possible to add all HTML element names? What about Angular.JS directives? CoffeeScript? The list of items that would be useful to add goes on and on. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible. There is this [TernJS Plugin](https://github.com/mortalapeman/LT-TernJS) for improving JavaScript autocomplete, though I haven't tried it myself yet.